# Cordova Oauth post base64 Image to Twitter

Tags: cordova, http, post, twitter, media

Basically I am trying to upload `base64 image` to twitter over this url; `upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json`. I read [twitter ref](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload) and I tried many ways to post (http) base64 image to twitter but didn't work. Here is my codes;

```
    /* creating sign. first */
                createTwitterSignature('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', tuserTWToken, tuserTWSecret, postMessage, base64B);



    /* http post*/
                $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
                    params: {
                            media: base64B
                            },
                    headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                             }
                    }).success(function (result) {
                                    console.log("OMSSMSS::: " + result);
                                }).error(function (error) {
                                    console.log("TWWWERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                });



                //Create the Signature
            function createTwitterSignature(method, url, usertoken, usersecret, message, mediaData) {
                    console.log("creating sign.");
                    var oauthObject = {
                                        oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
                                        oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(32),
                                        oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
                                        oauth_token: usertoken,
                                        oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
                                        oauth_version: "1.0",
                                    };

            var signatureObj =      $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url,
                                            oauthObject, {
                                            media: mediaData
                                        }, clientSecret, usersecret);
                                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization =
                                    signatureObj.authorization_header;

                                    console.log("Done sign");
                                }
```

It returns Error but not an error code. Response:

> TWWWERROR: """

I don't understand what was wrong here..

Comment: How are you debugging your app? try to print the error object without the `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @JoseRojas it is returning empty if I try without JSON.stringify

Comment: You're testing your app in a device or in a browser? in case to be in a browser what is shown in `Network` tab?

Comment: @JoseRojas device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved it after 2 days.
Here is the code;

```
                    createTwitterSignature('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', tuserTWToken, tuserTWSecret, postMessage, base64B);

                                $http({
                                    method: "post",
                                    url: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
                                    headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                                    },
                                    transformRequest: function (obj) {
                                        var str = [];
                                        for (var p in obj)
                                            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                                        return str.join("&");
                                    },
                                    data: {
                                        media_data: base64B
                                    }
                                }).success(function (result) {
                                console.log("OMSSMSS::: " + result);
                            }).error(function (error) {
                                console.log("TWWWERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                           });

                           //Create the Signature
                                function createTwitterSignature(method, url, usertoken, usersecret, message, mediaData) {
                                    console.log("creating sign.");
                                    var oauthObject = {
                                        oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
                                        oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(32),
                                        oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
                                        oauth_token: usertoken,
                                        oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
                                        oauth_version: "1.0"
                                    };
                      var signatureObj =  $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url,
                                        oauthObject, {
                                        media_data: mediaData
                                    }, clientSecret, usersecret);
                                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization =
                                signatureObj.authorization_header;

                                console.log("Done sign");
                            }
```